# configurate multichannel ASIO4ALL v2.13

Tags: matlab, audio, channel, asio

So I have a device (logilink sound box ua0099) with 6 channels or 8. It doesn't have ASIO. I installed ASIO4ALL. But I don't know what to do to have acces to each channel to choose a specific channel and play a sound on it.

This is my program in matlab`

```
function BasicSoundOutputDemo( wavfilename1,wavfilename2)

AssertOpenGL;

[y, freq] = psychwavread(wavfilename1);
[y1, freq1] = psychwavread(wavfilename2);
aux = y';
aux1 = y1';
wavedata = [aux1(1,:) ; aux(1,:)];
nrchannels = size(wavedata,1); % Number of rows == number of channels.

InitializePsychSound;
devices = PsychPortAudio('GetDevices' );

pahandle = PsychPortAudio('Open', 18, [], 0, freq, nrchannels);

PsychPortAudio('FillBuffer', pahandle, wavedata);

t1 = PsychPortAudio('Start', pahandle, 1, 0);

KbReleaseWait;


while ~KbCheck
  % Wait a seconds...
  WaitSecs(1);

end


PsychPortAudio('Stop', pahandle);
PsychPortAudio('Close', pahandle);
```

`
Device id 18 is [image: this]

When ASIO4ALL opens I have out 8X [image]

*My question is this can I control the speakers that I plug in the SUROUND, FRONT and BASS/CENTER with what I have? If yes , how?*

*If not, what do I need? Another tool? A better device?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no configurations needed. i just choose in matlab the asio4all device and choose the channels